# OS X Audio Queues in a 64-bit Environment Issues

Tags: macos, 64-bit, core-audio, audioqueue

I've recently ported my entire application to 64-bit and everything is working fine except for my audio recorder.  Even though the correct parameters (such as sample rate) are being reported when I check the resulting file's information in Quicktime, the file either has consistent gaps, is playing at a much higher speed, or is playing at a much lower speed.

I should note that I explicitly type all of my variables, in that I use descriptive types names such as UInt32 and SInt16 for everything instead of using plain 'int' or 'long